# Xamarin and Firebase Picker Data

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a one picker and I have one Firebase Database. And I wanna add data my picker.
How can I add data from my firebase database in a picker in my Xamarin form ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Both of these things are well documented.

Comment: I don't know how to investigate I'm new

Comment: I know how to add data in picker. But I am using firebase

Comment: there a numerous existing questions, posts, articles, videos, samples, etc on using Firebase.  Please take the time to read them.  Here's one to get you started: https://medium.embengineering.com/getting-started-with-xamarin-forms-and-firebase-databases-c2d7ba432998